# CSS divs for responsive screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I have logo and logo name as text to display. Please see the image below to understand my problem clearly.
Most tips and answers found are using absolute positioning but this doesnt match my requirements.
[image]

**div class boxes:**
Yellow: container , Green: for logo, blue: logo text or logo name as text

All the correct display to achieve are found on the right side of the sample div layout image above.

**Problem Summary:**

1. Everything will be working fine if both div(logo and logo text) are floated left **BUT** the only problem is its floated on top. How will I display the "logo text" at the bottom of the "container"?
2. Is this possible without positioning the "logo text" to absolute?

For now the div container, logo, and logo text classes are floated left.

Comment: nice drawing it shows it pretty well, if you have the possibility to add a jsFiddle or some code that would help even more

Comment: @daniel ..every div for now is floated left (as the current first display shows). I think no need to add code as I already stated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `display: inline-block` with `vertical-align: bottom;` gets you where you want to be;

```
<div class=logo>logo</div>
<div class=name>name</div>​

.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
.name {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bttom;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

​

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/CDBHT/

Answer (score 0):

Resize the result window to see the effect.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HyN54/3/)

Making your child div's `inline-block` is the solution. Also you will need to give a `max-width` and `min-height` attributes to your container so that it re-sizes to fit your contents. See this solution-

HTML-

```
<div id="con">
    <div id="lo"></div>
    <div id="tex"></div>
</div>
```

CSS-

```
#con
{
    max-width:310px;
    min-height:140px;
    background:yellow;
    border: 1px solid aqua;
}

#lo
{
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    background:green;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

#tex
{
    width:160px;
    height:60px;
    background:orange;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```